# input field not updating dynamically in angular 11 reactive form

Tags: angular, api, angular-material, angular-ui, updating

I am working on an angular project and want to update my reactive form field dynamically and data is coming from the API named `getNextCode()`. I call API service in

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.NextCodeService.getNextCode().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {

        this.nextCode = data;
        this.f.code.setValue(this.nextCode);
        this.f.code.disable();

      }, (err: any) => this.handleErr(err)
    );
}
```

I am using `form` control to update my input field. When I open the form,  field is disabled and its value is set from the `getNextCode()` API. But field  input value is not set and `disable` call does not work.

Comment: Add html code and form declaration to understand the question better. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the field you are trying to change isn't updating because it can't find the field you are trying to update in the reactive form since you are trying to access the field directly.

Change your code from this:

```
this.f.code.setValue(this.nextCode);
this.f.code.disable();
```

To:

```
this.frmGroup.get('code').setValue(this.nextCode);
this.frmGroup.get('code').disable();
```

Comment: do not work for me ..f is actually a function that returns from controls and code is form control name of a particular input field that's value need to be updated

Comment: Can you post the code inside your function f as well?

Comment: no i cannot because api must be called in ngOnInit(): void  function firstly this function is callled in life cycle hook

Comment: What is the variable name of your form group?

Comment: frmGroup is my from group name and i get control of this form group using  this function                                                                                   
get f() {
    return this.frmGroup.controls;
  }

Comment: You can't use your getter to set a value in your form group. You need to access the form group variable directly. I updated the answer with your form group variable name.